# EF code first inserting many rows

Tags: .net, entity-framework, code-first

I'm using EF code first and I need to insert many rows into a table, a couple of thousand records, I have in a generic list. Just doing a foreach loop and adding each entity to the table and finish with a SaveChanges() takes quite a while.

Is there a bulky way of doing this with EF or code first or should I do SqlCommand or SqlBulkCopy instead? Also, is there something I can switch off in EF code first to make the inserts faster?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I wish I could get some more tips on how to make inserting rows with EF code first faster, but I guess it's not doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `SaveChanges()` less often.

However, nothing you can do with the EF will approach the performance of something like SqlBulkCopy.

Comment: +1 ORM has never and will never be a performant solution for bulk operations.

Comment: Just doing dbContext.Entityname.Add() 4000 times takes 20-30 seconds. The SaveChanges() after the loop takes over 10 seconds. Probably going for SqlBulkCopy...